# array string from StreamReader to List<string> in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I get the next response from `new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding):`

**"["text1","text2","text3"]"**

How can I convert that into a `List<string>`

Comment: That's JSON you need to deserialize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to add the [Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

Then, try to deserialize that string to a list like this:

```
string response = "[\"text1\",\"text2\",\"text3\"]";
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(response);
```

Usage: [Deserialize a Collection](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCollection.htm)